Remove the empty object using jolt
When the name is present, it will be enhanced with '' at the prefix and postfix, like '*Hello*'. However, if the name is absent, it adds only '**'. When the name is optional, how can I avoid adding only '**' when the request is absent? It is same for addressLine1, addressLine2 as well.
Updates: In the below request postalCode and tour properties should not be enhanced.
Input.json
{
  "search": {
    "party": {
      "name": "AccountName",
      "tour": "TourName"
    },
    "address": {
      "addressLine1": "US",
      "postalCode": "psCode"
    }
  }
}


JoltTransformation
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "search": {
        "party": {
          "name": "AccountName",
          "tour": "Tour"
        },
        "address": {
          "addressLine1": "add1",
          "addressLine2": "add2",
          "postalCode": "psCode"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "AccountName": "=concat('*',@(1,AccountName),'*')",
      "add1": "=concat('*',@(1,add1),'*')",
      "add2": "=concat('*',@(1,add2),'*')"
    }
  }
]



ActualOutput.json
{
  "AccountName" : "*AccountName*",
  "Tour" : "TourName",
  "add1" : "*US*",
  "add2" : "*UK*",
  "psCode" : "psCode"
}



ActualdOutput.json : When addressLine2 is missing, it adds **
{
  "AccountName" : "*AccountName*",
  "Tour" : "TourName",
  "add1" : "*US*",
  "psCode" : "psCode",
  "add2" : "**"
}



In the actual output I would like to eliminate "SecondaryRatings" : { } in the response

Can you please elaborate more why you have used the default spec, what type of inputs might you encounter .. etc ? Btw, are you OK with your previous question's solution ?

@BarbarosÖzhan I have updated the question, there is no default section in the jolt. I have update the question. I have accepted the previous question, thanks for the help.

Seems you need to remove add2 in this case rather than non-existing SecondaryRatings, don't you ?

UK is missing for the new input ...

No need to add asteriskes individually, but do it in a generic way just by replacing the current modify spec with the following one :
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*ame|add*": "=concat('*',@(1,&),'*')" // @(1,&) is a replacement for 
        // the current elements 
    }
  }

by this the unwanted attributes will become extinct spontaneously and only related restricted attributes sets are impacted.

This solution applies to all properties, but there may be other properties inside the party and address that should not be affected by this change.

@RakeshGR Then need to see your real situation in a minimal and reproducible manner along with containing all those cases in to be able to get more robust solutions.

I have update the question with actual input request with optional and all the parameters.

currently no problem, the same solution handles your case except for UK which's already missing. @RakeshGR

{
  "AccountName" : "*AccountName*",
  "Tour" : "*TourName*",
  "add1" : "*US*",
  "psCode" : "*psCode*"
}

It applies to all the fields, but it should only apply for AccountName, addr1, addr2 only other properties should be as it is.
@barbarps

I've just edited @RakeshGR , btw, there are double ActualOutput

Thanks it it working as expected. Can you please remove duplicate double quotes in this line.
""ame|add"": "=concat('',@(1,&),'')"
it is working as expected.
I have shared two ActualOutput because of show case when values are empty or null it is just appending "*".

@RakeshGR oh my bad, just removed them. Take care

When AccountName, add1 are adding to "**" when they are null in the request. Expected should be those properties should be ignore. When it is not present or if the value is null.

{
"search": {
"party": {
"name": null,
"tour": "TourName"
},
"address": {
"addressLine1": "US",
"postalCode": "psCode"
}
}
}
When name is null it is adding AccountName : ** to the output @Barbaros Ozhan
